# Getting user input with CONFIRM

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i need to get the user to click OK or CANCEL:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CallRecursive(TreeView1);

        string confirmationMessage;
        confirmationMessage = @"Please review the data before submitting:" +  "\r\n"
        + "Sample Received Date: " + received_dateTextbox.Text + "\r\n"
        + "Site of Ocurrence: " + site_of_occurrenceTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
        + "Occurrence Date: " + occurrence_dateTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
        + "Report Date: " + report_byTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
        + "Specimen ID: " + spec_idTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
        + "Batch ID: " + batch_idTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
        + "Report Initiated By: " + report_byTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
        + "Problem Identified By: " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue + "\r\n"
        + nodetexts;

        HiddenFieldConfirmation.Value = confirmationMessage;

************i need function ConfirmWithUser() to run here from javascript*************


            if (HiddenFieldUserConfirmed.Value != "no")
        {
            SubmitData();

            CallRecursive(TreeView1);
            nodetexts += ";";
        }
    }
```

here is the javascript:

```
function ConfirmWithUser() {
            if (confirm(document.getElementById('HiddenFieldConfirmation').value) == true)

                            { document.getElementById('HiddenFieldUserConfirmed').value='yes'; }

                                else

                            { document.getElementById('HiddenFieldUserConfirmed').value='no';}
```

how do i run this function `ConfirmWithUser()` on the button click inside of the code behind code as shown above:

another words i need:

1. after user clicks button, first part of codebehind execeutes
2. javascript inside of codebehind exeuctes
3. the last part of code behind executes

Comment: You do not understand the HTTP model.  Your design cannot possibly work; you need a separate postback after setting the value in the client.

Comment: That is fundamentally impossible.  You need to learn about HTTP and client-server programming.

Comment: @slaks you need to have a chag sameach IMMEDIATELY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Javascript variable named `confirmationMessage`.
You need to call `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` and insert the server-side variable's value as a Javascript string literal.

However, your design cannot possibly work; the `if (HiddenFieldUserConfirmed.Value != "no")` will run (on the server) before the Javascript client-side code.

You need to understand how HTTP and client/server separation works.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code where the code is run.

You need to register the script in the page_load inside an !ispostback section. You then need to check the hidden value in response to a button click handler for example.

**More detail after edit**

You need to move the code that creates your javascript message to your page_load & register an onclientclick handler with the javascript function. This will then fire that javascript when you click the button, populating your hidden field and then submitting the form to be handled server side.